# How to customize files obtained from RTW

Tags: matlab, simulink, rtw

I use Matlab R2008a and I try to replace handmade C code with code generate from Simulink model.
I've reach a good result but in some file I've an unnecessary  function , generated to initialize the data structure : _initialize().
Now, how can avoid the generation of this function? 
More in general, is possible configure RTW so to generate only one *.c and only one *.h files (except rtwtypes.h)

Thanks for your suggestion

Below my configuartion :

MATLAB                                                Version 7.6
Simulink                                              Version 7.1
Real-Time Workshop                                    Version 7.1
Real-Time Workshop Embedded Coder                     Version 5.1

Comment: Not sure if that answers the question, but it's certainly related: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/92639-how-do-i-customize-the-main-function-generated-by-real-time-workshop-embedded-coder-5-2-r2008b

Comment: Hi, maybe is a good start point...thanks

Comment: Why would you think initialize is unnecessary? Where would you put it otherwise? An option for you is to use the rt_main to wrap the initialize and output/update functions into one single function that you call from wherever you are hooking the generated code into.

Comment: Hi, because the data structure initialization is made in other function.
As I written, my target is replace a part or all handmade C code, for this reason I would proceed for simple step so to reduce the impact on the project.